# Exporting Imagery in ArcGIS - problems with lines on exported image?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, export, imagery, world-imagery

I am using the pan-sharpened Landsat imagery that is available on ArcGIS Desktop (ie data from ArcGIS Online).

When I export a map with the pan-sharpened Landsat imagery in the background, lines show up on the image. However, this does not show when I am looking at the image in ArcGIS 10. I am enclosing an excerpt of both the exported map (top) and the screenshot of how it looks in ArcGIS (bottom) so you can see the problem. Can you please help me – how can I export the map without the lines?

Someone from Esri suggested that I turn off the DRA however I think that I am unable to do this as it is a file that I brought in from ArcGIS Online. When I access the Image Analysis window, it seems like the DRA box is not clickable. Also, he suggested that I use calculate statistics or build pyramids and statistics tool on the source data. Again, I don’t think I can do this since it is a file from ArcGIS Online.

If someone can help me do any of the above with the ArcGIS Online file or how I might be able to fix this problem in a different way, please let me know what I might be doing wrong.

[image: Exported Map]
[image: Screen shot]

Answer (score 2):

The default rendered for the Landsat services has DRA (Dynamic Range Adjustment) turned on. When exporting/printing multiple requests are made and each has a different stretch applied (hence the stripes). Go to the layer properties and use a stretch that uses the dataset statistics or define custom statistics. If using an image service go to Layer dialog,  'Processing Templates' tab set the processing to one that does not include DRA.
The computation of statistics is applicable only if you have loaded the source landsat scenes.